# Cant close an iframe in google chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox

im using an iframe from the fancybox plugin. I can close the iframe in every browser excpect google chrome with the javascript order:

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

or:

```
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
```

just google chrome refuses to do his job in this case.

The error message of the console is:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/exampleuser/Desktop/index.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/exampleuser/Desktop/Version42/index.html#. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
pidgin.js:357Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined

My frame is local at the moment if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `parent.postMessage()` ([described here](http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe)) and listen in on `window.onmessage` at the parent to invoke `$.fancybox.close()`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your code but Google Chrome won't let you work with ajax or iframes (and fancybox) locally. You need to upload your files to a server to make it work.